# Issue using axios in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I can't seem figure out what's causing the following issue when using `axios`:

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js 17:10-24
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'C:\Users...    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
            - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
            - install 'url'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
            resolve.fallback: { "url": false }
    
    webpack compiled with 1 error
```

So, I am using axios when a user submits a value via input field; It triggers the following function posting the data and retrieving the values from the backend based on the posted data.

```
import React, {useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import {TextField } from "@mui/material";


function Model () {
  

  const [input,setInput] = useState ('');

  const keyPress = (e) => {

    if(e.keyCode === 13 || e.key === 'Enter' ){
      e.preventDefault();
 
      setInput(e.target.value)
      const data = e.target.value
   
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/Data',data)
      .then( res => {
        console.log(res)
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Message is not set maybe bc of :",err);
        
      })

    }
  }

  // render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className='container'>

        <div id='serachBoxConatiner'>
          <TextField fullWidth label="Enter here..." id="fullWidth"
            onChange={input}  
            onKeyPress={keyPress}
          />
        </div>

         
        </div>
      </>

    );
}
```

export default Model

I have tried to delete and reinstall `axios`, I tried to us `npm install` to see if I that would help but nothing worked so far.

Comment: Where did you define `data`?

Comment: How have you imported `axios` into your component? FYI version 0.27.2 no longer tries to import the `url` module

Comment: Hi @SinanYaman, I have updated the code the data was suppose to be the input value (e.target.value).

Comment: Hi Phil Yes, I have imported axios in my component.

Answer (score 0):

Since `e.target.value` is going to be a `string`, you can't post that as an axios request payload. You need to send json objects as exampled [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example). Can you try something like this (depending on what is the keyword for your endpoint):

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/Data',{
        search: data
      })
      .then( res => {
        console.log(res)
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Message is not set maybe bc of :",err);
        
      })
```

*Remember `search` is not necessary, it can be any name based on your endpoint*

Comment: Thank you for suggesting Sinan but I am still having the same error for some reason.

Comment: what axios version are you using?

Comment: I am using `"axios": "^0.27.0"` version

Comment: thank you for your help I wanted to let you know I was able to find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70865447/15068478)